# How to wait in calabash-android for next activity if activity name is not known

Tags: android, calabash

Can I get any flag from calabash-android method which returns that page is still loading? I need to automate internet based application where wait is vary depending on internet speed and server load. How to set wait time or is there any way i will query to calabash-android which returns loading status of page.

Comment: you can wait untill a text from the second activity is loaded.

Comment: how I can determine text is loaded because it shows progressbar with loading text?

Comment: see this link. https://github.com/calabash/calabash-android/blob/master/ruby-gem/lib/calabash-android/canned_steps.md this will help you. as soon as you click on one activity and want to go to the other .instead of giving time in miliseconds to wait give the text of the second activity to appear.And then do the next step.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`wait_for`](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-android/blob/feat/console-should-respect-irbrc/documentation/ruby_api.md#wait_foroptions-block) method. For instance:

```
wait_for(:timeout => 10, :retry_frequency => 0.2) { query("ProgressBar").empty? }
```

It waits for condition to be true until timeout runs out.